# Prime and maximal ideals. I only have the definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a ring and $P$ be a proper bilateral ideal of $A$. Show that $P$ is prime if, and only if, for every pair of elements $a, b \in A$ it is satisfied $aAb \subseteq P ⇔a \in P$ or $b \in P$.

**Note**. The concept of ***Prime Ideal*** that I am dealing with is: $I$ is said to be a prime ideal of $A$ if for any $I_1$ and $I_2$ bilateral ideals of $A$ it is held that: $I_1$$I_2$ $\subseteq$ $I$ $⇔$ $I_1$ ⊆ $I$, or, $I_2 ⊆ I.$ I only have the definition, can you help me with a path?

**Note**.Consider that $1 \in A$.

My attempt was: Given that $1 \in A$, $a1b \in aAb \subseteq I$. Thus, $ab \in I$. To prove that $a \in I$ or $b \in I$, I plan to assume without loss of generality that if $a \in I$ then $b \in I$, but I have no clear idea how to relate having $ab \in I$ and $a \notin I$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is o in your definition?

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg.  I have already made the modifications, sorry.

Comment: You know that $ab \in I$. You want to get a statement of the form $I_1 I_2 \subseteq I$, because then you could use your definition of prime ideal. Seems like $I_1 = (a)$ and $I_2 = (b)$ is a natural choice-- is it true that $I_1 I_2 \subseteq I$?

Comment: Please use a descriptive, specific title next time.  And search around a bit first.  You'll find a great deal of questions like this already have solutions.